# How to reach more history data from High and Low arrays

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

i have this code .. does somebody know how to reach more historic bars?

```
void OnTick()

  {


   ChartNavigate(0, CHART_END, 0);

   Print(High[2000]);

  }
```

this gives me error but with usage of High[1000] it works.

I tried that ChartNavigate funciton but it does not help.

Thanks!!

Comment: The history available using the High variable is not related to using ChartNavigate. The oldest High data that is available is High[Bars-1]

Comment: How to get Bars number extended?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of bars that you have loaded on the chart.

To reach the number of bars on current time frame use:

```
int bars = Bars;

Print(High[bars-1]);
```

or if you want to know how many bars are loaded in another time frame (e.g Daily) you can use :

```
int bars = iBars(_Symbol,PERIOD_D1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I extended this number somehow? As i can see 140 bars for example and need to see 3000 ...

Comment: My pleasure. If you see 140 bars, It means that you have not downloaded more than 140 bars from the MT4 server. So you won't be able to read data more than that.